# Create new column in panda data frame

Tags: python, string, pandas

I'm extremely new to python and have been searching google and stackoverflow to solve this issue which I am sure is simply a syntax problem.

I have a data frame with several columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/path/file.csv")
```

My csv has 5 columns and ~ 100k rows
I simply want a substring of the first 2 digits of column 5.

I've tried:

```
df.assign(new = lambda x: x.column5[0:2],)
```

This creates the new field and populates the first two rows with the complete value in column 5 and gives me NaN for the remainder.

These attempts give me syntax erros:

```
df['new'] = df['column5'].str[0:2]
df.map(lambda df['column5']: [:2])
```

I am simply at a loss of how to create a new column using the first two digits of an existing column from a table read in via pandas.

If this were SAS I'd have been done hours ago, but I am trying to make a go of Python so your help is appreciated

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide the error stack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `column5` column is of int*/float* dtype, so
try to convert it to string first:

```
df['new'] = df['column5'].astype(str).str[:2]
```

you can explicitly specify types of columns when reading CSV file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', ..., dtype={'column5': object})
```

Comment: That fixed it.  I need to see if I can force pandas read.csv to read fields as strings rather than int when dealing with codes expressed as numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  The Python for Everybody series from U Mich on Coursera doesn't cover Pandas :(

Comment: @RustyCoder, you are welcome. Good luck with Pandas! :)